# Set proxy globally in Ubuntu server for ALL application

Tags: server, proxy

Ubuntu Server 16/18.

There are a lot of apps run inside the server including but not limited to docker,npm,maven,gradle,etc.

I am tired to set proxy for each application. Is it possible to set that globally?

Note: when I say globally I mean EVERY CONNECTION including package downloading by `apt-get`, artifact downloading by `maven/gradle/npm` from docker build or run process.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to set environnement variables in each process .

I suppose that `192.168.88.88:3128` is the ip port for my squid proxy .

On ubuntu 18.04 ( my test machine )

You must :

1. modify `/etc/environment` by adding these lines :

```
FTP_PROXY="http://192.168.88.88:3128/"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://192.168.88.88:3128/"
HTTP_PROXY="http://192.168.88.88:3128/"
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1"
ftp_proxy="http://192.168.88.88:3128/"
http_proxy="http://192.168.88.88:3128/"
https_proxy="http://192.168.88.88:3128/"
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1"
```

2. modify `/etc/systemd/system.conf` in the section `[Manager]` by adding this one big line :

```
DefaultEnvironment="FTP_PROXY=http://192.168.88.88:3128/" "HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.88.88:3128/" "HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.88.88:3128/" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1" "ftp_proxy=http://192.168.88.88:3128/" "http_proxy=http://192.168.88.88:3128/" "https_proxy=http://192.168.88.88:3128/" "no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1"
```

3. You must reboot the server to restart process .
4. You can verify that every process has the right setting you can run this command :

```
(
for PROCPID in /proc/[1-9]* ;
do
    FENV=${PROCPID}/environ ; 
    C=$(sudo strings $FENV | grep -c -i 'proxy.*=' ) ;
    PCMDL=$(sudo strings ${PROCPID}/cmdline | tr '\n' ' ') ;
    PID=$(basename $PROCPID) ;
    PCOMM=$(sudo strings ${PROCPID}/comm) ;
    printf '%s:%s:%s:%s\n' "$C" "$PID" "$PCMDL"  "$PCOMM"
done
)
```

This command do a loop for each process currently running and will count environnment variables that a name that contains proxy .
if a line start with `8:`, that means you have 8 env variables that have this process .

Comment: What if I want to use WPAD or a PAC url?